# React Router match is undefined using Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router

I'm doing a simple eCommerce PoC using react and TypeScript. The problem is I cannot pass props to a product detail page neither accessing the `match` that contains the `params`

I have the following in my Routes pages

```
const Routes = () => (
    <Router>
        <Switch>
            <Route path="/" exact component={require("../pages/home").default} />
            <Route path="/shop" exact component={require("../pages/shop").default} />
            <Route path="/shop/:name" component={require("../pages/shop/details").default} />
        </Switch>
    </Router>
)
```

In the Shop page I call `Link` like this:

```
<Link to={`/shop/${product.name}`}> 
  <Card 
  ... // A card with product info
   </Card>
 </Link>
```

And finally the `details` like so:

```
import React from 'react';
import { match } from 'react-router-dom';
import MainLayout from '../../layout/mainLayout';
import './shop.css';

interface IProduct {
  name: string
}

export const ProductDetail = (matched: match<IProduct>) => {
  console.log(matched); // Undefined

  return (
    <>
    </>
  )
};


export default MainLayout(ProductDetail);
```

I want to access the name of the product in order to fetch all it's information and I should be able of so using `match.params.name` but it's undefined.

I already tried this options 
https://medium.com/@bopaiahmd.mca/how-to-pass-props-using-link-and-navlink-in-react-router-v4-75dc1d9507b4
https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/react-router-typescript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need [withRouter HOC](https://www.reactandtypescript.dev/examples/react-router)

```js
interface ProductDetailProps {
  match: {
    params: {
      name: string
    }
  }
}

export const ProductDetail: React.FC<RouteComponentProps<ProductDetailProps>> = withRouter(({match: {params: {name} = {}} = {}} = {}) => {
  console.log(name); 

  return (
    <>
    </>
  )
});
```

Comment: What a life savior. I made some adjustments to make it work. `export const ProductDetail: React.FC<RouteComponentProps<ProductDetailProps>> = ({ match }) =>`  kept the interface with only name and in the end changed to `export default MainLayout(withRouter(ProductDetail));`
Thanks a lot!